# Why does my CSS ordered list ignore margin?

Tags: css, css-float

Screenshot:

[image]

The image has a `float:left` attribute. As you can see the numbers for the ordered lists are too far to the left, but adding a `margin-left:20px` to the `<ol>` tag doesn't help. (Neither does adding it for the `<li>`s, by the way, but that would be bad practice anyway.)

How can I move my `<ol>` to the right?

Comment: have you tried to add padding-left?

Answer (score 3):

You can control placement of bullet items with list-style-position property. Try this:

```
ol li {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Check the demo for how it works:

```css
.fixed ol li {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo" style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;">
    <h3>Without list-style-position</h3>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/2" style="float: left" />
    <ol>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ol>
</div>

<div class="fixed" style="float: left">
    <h3>With list-style-position</h3>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/2" style="float: left" />
    <ol>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only indents the first line to make place for the numbering. I would like to have the whole `<li>` placed more to the right.

Comment: Can you add HTML structure and your styles? Or better create a simple demo.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can move the list to the right using `position:relative`?

http://jsfiddle.net/L6Lhtu2m/

```
ol {
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
}
```

Comment: Almost! I had to add a `padding-right:20px;` as well, otherwise the text moved outside my page. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a fiddle of that fix? I wasn't able to prevent the text moving with just a padding. I'm curious how you did it.

Comment: I have to find out about this fiddling thing, I'll see what I can do. Meanwhile, the page I'm talking about is a fixed-width div. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I found `margin-left` works after all, but I have to add the image's width, so not

```
margin-left:20px;
```

but rather

```
margin-left:430px; /* 410px image width + 20px right margin
```

Thanks for the other answers, all.